# Trailblazer Reform: validation_groups crashing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, trailblazer

I'm setting up a deployment of Trailblazer, however I'm a new Rails user and I could use a little direction about this problem.

I've installed all the required Gems, however the `Reform` gem, is not running properly and it's throwing an error.

```
 loading extension..."/Users/smilingbuddha/web/aardvark/app/concepts/recent_upgrade/contract"
   Exiting
  /Users/smilingbuddha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/reform-2.2.1/lib/reform/validation.rb:6:in `validation_groups': undefined local variable or method `validation_group_class' for RecentUpgrade::Contract::Create:Class (NameError)
  Did you mean?  validation_groups
        from /Users/smilingbuddha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/reform-2.2.1/lib/reform/validation.rb:13:in `validation'
        from /Users/smilingbuddha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/reform-2.2.1/lib/reform/validation.rb:19:in `validates' 
        from /Users/smilingbuddha/web/aardvark/app/concepts/recent_upgrade/contract.rb:8:in `<class:Create>'
        from /Users/smilingbuddha/web/aardvark/app/concepts/recent_upgrade/contract.rb:3:in `<module:Contract>'
        from /Users/smilingbuddha/web/aardvark/app/concepts/recent_upgrade/contract.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

This is the error:

`validation_groups: undefined local variable or method validation_group_class for RecentUpgrade::Contract::Create:Class (NameError)`

Any ideas how I can get this application running? 
Thank you!

Here's a section of the validation code we are using in the application in `contract.rb`

```
 property :property_id
 validates :property_id, presence: true
```

Comment: I was able to find that there is a version mismatch in the `reform` gem which I was able to correct by appending the required version to number to my `Gemfile`.
`gem 'reform', '~> 2.1.0'`